# Data import via Stored procedure or Triggers

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, import, database-trigger

We've a legacy system (MAS200 if you need to know) and there's an old vbs script which pull data from MAS and populates two staging tables in our production SQL database. And after some processing / cleanup that data goes into actual tables.

```
Data flow : MAS200 --> Staging tables --> Production table
```

To simplify consider there's an "Order" parent table and an "Items" child table. Order can have multiple items, each item record will have an FK OrderId. So, during import first we import the Order data and create an entry in the "Order" table and then fetch "Items" entries and import them.

**Existing TRIGGER based approach -**
At present we've two TRIGGERs - one on each staging table (Order & Items). So each new insert is tapped, and after processing data a new entry is inserted into actual production table. My only concern is that the trigger is executed for each Items entry instead of BULK insert. And it seems less manageable.

**SP based approach -**
If I remove both the TRIGGERs then import data into staging tables and finally execute an SP which will import Order data and then perform a BULK insert into the Items table. Could that be more efficient / faster?

*Its not a comparison actually just a diff design. I'd like to know which one seems better or if there's a 3rd better approach to import from MAS to production SQL db.*

**EDIT 1 :** Thanks. *As asked by many - the data volume is not big or too frequent.* Lets say 10-12 Orders (with 20-30 Items) every hour. Also with TRIGGERs, thought we don't get a TRANSACTION but only two simple TRIGGERs are suffice. I believe more scripting is needed with SP.

Goal : Need to keep it as simple, clean and efficient as possible.

Comment: Are your staging tables on the same server as the production tables?

Comment: Yes both staging and prod tables are in the same DB. However, MAS and the vbs script are on a diff server. Also if items are more then we face delay.

Comment: If I were doing this, I would use an SP, as it will almost certainly be faster and will allow you to control your transactions better. Depending on the amount of data being transferred, I would choose between a BULK INSERT (following what @elirevach suggests) for large amounts of data, or using a normal INSERT (or MERGE if some columns may change) more moderate sizes.

Comment: @HemantTank, ignoring the trigger is a bit risky, but sometimes we take the risk as possibility of failure is very low and it may worth to keep it simple..

Answer (score 1):

Using Triggers:

- Pros:
  The data sync is real time. As you create data by data entry, the volume of data should not be big, so having bulk insert doesn't improve a lot. performance using trigger is good enough
- Cons:
  Data sync is not real time and if the connection breaks between MAS200 and production, you'll have a big problem. Also (as you mentioned) you can not have transaction, which is a big issue.

I suggest you use SP to transfer data in a time interval basis (if you can tolerate synchronization delay).

Comment: Good point. To add my 2 cents - a TRANSACTION approach is also not possible with TRIGGERs. FYI, the volume of data is - one Order can have upto 30-40 Items. So what do you say ?

Comment: good point on Transaction. how many order you have per minute? you can easily transfer a few hundred thousand records in less than 10 secs. So I think you won't have any problem performance wise. You'll be able to sync every minute easily with no impact on server performance.

Comment: I've revised - pls see Edit 1 and let me know your thoughts. I don't want to make it biased.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want fast approach , you need :

1)  to disable the FK on the ITEMS table  for the duration of the load

2)  then LOAD the ORDERS , and then enable the FK

All this should be done using SP , trigger approach is safe but very slow when its come to large bulks load

I hope you will find it useful

Thanks

Comment: This is an ongoing setup and Orders will be imported frequently - switching FK on & off is not an option. I've revised - pls see Edit 1. Thx

Comment: Many time we see situations when FK is being enforced on both sites , application and DB , if you can make sure that your application already validate this FK (select to check if parent is exists before data is inserted to child ) , in many time you can just disable it , it will improve your performance and simplify your solution

Comment: Got it, but we need to persist FK in DB.